# Add newline after every paragraph in log file in vi editor

Tags: substitute

I want to add new line after every paragraph in vi editor. How do I do it?

The new line is located by the date and time in this format

```
2023-11-26 14:14:14
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: The back and forth in the comments and the ambiguous wording show that this question lacks details. Can we have a more realistic **before/after** example? If you want us to do your work, that's the least you can do.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
:%s/\d\{4}-\d\{2}-\d\{2} \d\{2}:\d\{2}:\d\{2}/\r&/
```

Or:

```
:%s/\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d/\r&/
```

It inserts a new line after every date in the format you specified.

Comment: "New line" != "Newline".

Comment: @romainl What do you mean?

Comment: Colloquially, a "new line" is an empty line and a "newline" is an EOL character. The question is ambiguous because it uses the two expressions interchangeably. Your answer as well.

Comment: @romainl, thanks I have learned something. The question is vague and I suppose my answer should be improved. I suppose and example will help to be know if it is a New line or a Newline and where to insert it.

Comment: Your answer is working sir. Any idea to do this in less editor?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) I don't know the Less editor. I'm afraid I can't help you here ;-). If the solution address your need maybe you could accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: less is not an editor.

Comment: This is causing new line  after date instead of before data. LOL. @romainl was trying to say that.

Comment: I have updated the solution to have the newline before the date.

Comment: only the second one works. Thanks

Comment: The first form should also work :-| Are you sure you typed it correctly?